# Can we join two tables in postgresql if the tables are in different schemas?

Tags: postgresql

I have one table in `public` schema and a second table in `deepak` schema. Both the schemas are under same database.

Can I join data from these two tables?

Answer (score 34):

Sure, just use their fully-qualified names `public.t1 JOIN deepak.t2 USING (col)`.

Answer (score 19):

Yes, you just prepend the schema.

```
public.table
deepak.table
```